# How to fix my PHP inline if using ternary operator?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I saw an example in the PHP Manual:

```
<?php
$var = TRUE;
echo $var==TRUE ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; // get TRUE
echo $var==FALSE ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; // get FALSE
?>
```

and I am trying to integrate something similar as part of a single line output. My line looks like this:

```
echo "...text..." . $db_field['late']==0 ? ' ' : $db_field['late']  . "...more text...";
```

Logically what I want to do is: if 'late' = 0 then display nothing else display the content of 'late'.

Am I just trying to be too clever?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because the precedence of ternary operator `?:` is very low. To fix this, use brackets

```
echo "...text..." . ($db_field['late']==0 ? ' ' : $db_field['late']) . "...more text...";
```

[PHP Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Perfect. Worked a treat. No idea what a 'ternary operator' is but thanks.

Comment: A ternary operator is what you meant by "inline if"

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "...text..." . ( $db_field['late']==0 ? ' ' : $db_field['late'] )  . "...more text...";
```